# Weird behaviour of AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avplayer, avcomposition

I am merging multiple videos and playing it in AVPlayer. Video starts fine, but after sometime video freezes and only audio plays. I have a `UISlider` which helps to go forward or backward in video using `seekToTime:`.

So the weird part is that after video freezes, if I use the slider to go forward or backward, video starts playing perfectly fine. I have tried my app in multiple devices.

So basically I have to use `seekToTime:` method to give the video a nudge every time it freezes.

My code for merging video and playing back is following:

```
AVAsset *asset0 = [self currentAsset:0];
AVAsset *asset1 = [self currentAsset:1];
AVAsset *asset2 = [self currentAsset:2];
AVAsset *asset3 = [self currentAsset:3];
AVAsset *asset4 = [self currentAsset:4];

NSArray *assets = @[asset0, asset1, asset2, asset3, asset4];

AVMutableComposition *mutableComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoCompositionTrack = [mutableComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                                   preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioCompositionTrack = [mutableComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                                                                   preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

NSMutableArray *instructions = [NSMutableArray new];
CGSize size = CGSizeZero;

CMTime time = kCMTimeZero;
for (AVAsset *asset in assets)
{
    AVAssetTrack *assetTrack = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].firstObject;
    AVAssetTrack *audioAssetTrack = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio].firstObject;

    NSError *error;
    [videoCompositionTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, assetTrack.timeRange.duration)
                                   ofTrack:assetTrack
                                    atTime:time
                                     error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error - %@", error.debugDescription);
    }

    [audioCompositionTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, assetTrack.timeRange.duration)
                                   ofTrack:audioAssetTrack
                                    atTime:time
                                     error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error - %@", error.debugDescription);
    }

    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *videoCompositionInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    videoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(time, assetTrack.timeRange.duration);
    videoCompositionInstruction.layerInstructions = @[[AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoCompositionTrack]];
    [instructions addObject:videoCompositionInstruction];

    time = CMTimeAdd(time, assetTrack.timeRange.duration);

    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(size, CGSizeZero)) {
        size = assetTrack.naturalSize;;
    }
}

AVMutableVideoComposition *mutableVideoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
mutableVideoComposition.instructions = instructions;

mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = size;

pi = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:mutableComposition];
pi.videoComposition = mutableVideoComposition;

player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:[[CameraEngine engine] pi]];

player.volume = 0.75;
playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer: player];

playerLayer.frame = self.bounds;
[self.layer addSublayer: playerLayer];
[playerLayer setNeedsDisplay];
[player play];
```

**UPDATE** : Found out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285007/merging-two-m4v-movie-files-using-avmutablecomposition-videos-will-not-merge) which describes similar problem. But his solution is not well understood.

Comment: "But his solution is not well understood." What do you mean by that? It seems clear enough. Do you mean _you_ don't understand it?

Comment: Also, can you explain what you are doing with AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction?

Comment: Can you please comment the videoCompositionInstruction in your code and try the same. may be there is something wrong with that

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call `[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:[[CameraEngine engine] pi]]` instead of `[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:pi]`? Your construct your composition and assign it to `pi` while it is not used anywhere. Try to use `[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:pi]` instead.

If this will not help try to change your `videoComposition` generation. Try to do the following:

```
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *videoCompositionInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
videoCompositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, mutableComposition.timeRange.duration);
videoCompositionInstruction.layerInstructions = @[[AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:[mutableComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo].firstObject]];

AVMutableVideoComposition *mutableVideoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
mutableVideoComposition.instructions = @[videoCompositionInstruction];

mutableVideoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
mutableVideoComposition.renderSize = size;
```

after your `for` loop. Hope this helps!